# on one click, print page function call more than one time jquery

Tags: duplicates, live, jquery, die

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#posHold tbody tr').die();
   $('#posHold tbody tr').live('click', function () {

   $(".btnPrint").printPage({
        url: "receipts/void.jsp?ID=111",
        message:"Your document is being created"
    });

    $('.btnPrint').trigger('click');

    });
 });
```

When I click on tr one time , it print to a printer one time. When I click again on tr, it print to a printer 2 time and on next click 3 times and so on.....Even I also call .die() before .live()

How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: why triggering click instead of clicking on it directly?

Comment: Is your ".btnPrint" in the "TR" ?

Comment: for auto printing to a printer @undefined

Comment: <a class="btnPrint"></a> @Akarun

Comment: there is no need to trigger two events for calling one function, printPage acts like a click, and you trigger another click event and it's called 2 times.

Comment: if it call two time, then its means, on every click it should be multiple of 2, but it increment 1++; @undefined

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a.btnPrint').printPage({
        url: "receipts/void.jsp?ID=111",
        message:"Your document is being created"
    });
 });
```

Comment: I am using this jquery plugin https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-printPage-plugin

Comment: I have no any other option to trigger the click event , due to auto printing.

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor see their example, they use only an anchor tag, you should specify the href attribute for your a tag. http://www.position-absolute.com/creation/print/

Comment: If url not accessible then, he will move to href. This is optional.I have also tested by also specifying this